# Symfony 5 - How implement basic authentication on REST call

Tags: php, api, rest, symfony, basic-authentication

I have created a URL that take a request in method POST. He take a JSON and he return me a XML converted file.

I would like, before the request, a basic authorization ( just a password , i need not registered user )on this URL to allow the user make the request. But i don't understand how the authorization working on symfony.

I think that all i need is in this page of [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#reference-http-client)
but i get some errors and i not understand how it work (what is realme? What does it mean with Secured Area?)

This is my controller, how can i implement a basic authentication on this REST call ?

```
class IndexController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     * @Route("/converter-hl7", name="converter", methods={"POST"})
     */

    public function index(Request $request) {

        $json = $request->getContent();

        $converter = new HL7ConverterService($json, new ErrorService());
        $xml = $converter->outputXML();


        $response = new Response($xml);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'xml');

        return $response;
    }
    

}
```

Comment: An authentication how? Do you have the data for auth in the request? Do you have an user session already? You should put more data about it.

Comment: No, i need just a default password, no user and no database needed

Comment: Put any method to write the password before you send the request; then, you can use the password inside your controller, and send the xml if the password is correct.

Comment: but how can i write the password ? is not possible use basic authentication ?

Comment: But what do you want? How you want to do it?

Comment: I need do this with a simple basic authentication...but i don't need some user provider or class, just a simple password to acces at the rest call. All that i understood, is to modify framework.yaml  and put inside http_client, base_uri and auth_basic. The problem is that i never do that, and i don't understand what the doc said

Comment: If you need a simple password, send a password with the request and then, in the controller you can check the password and if is correct, send the xml.

Answer (score 2):

i use JWT for my API's to Control and Secure Api access
you should check [this Bundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle)
But to use this you need to create user .
if you don't want to create a user you could demand a password from the sender and integrate it in the request then control access based on that.

Comment: But i can't do this with a basic authentication ?

Comment: for a normal auth you will need a user but if you don't like to use users in your system, the only solution I can see is to send a password in the request as I and @MR Mark II told you

Comment: So if i undestand, you suggest me to put the password in the URL, get it and check if he s correct ?

Comment: it's not secure but better then nothing